# MongoDB - Query nested objects

Tags: mongodb

How do I retrieve only the types where the attribute exists.

Example:

```
{
    "_id": 1231333,
    "cars": {
        "type-123": {
            "attribute": "faster"
        },
        "type-1234": {
            "attribute": "slow"
        },
        "type-12345": {
            "attribute": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON contains a dplicated key `type-1234`. Please provide a valid one.

Comment: J.F Ok, I did fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregate query with `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` to get desired value programatically.

You can use this query:

- `$objectToArray` to convert cars object into an array to access the value.
- `$unwind` to match desired value (can use `$filter`).
- `$group` to undo the unwind.
- `$arrayToObject` to get the initial schema.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$set": {"cars": {"$objectToArray": "$cars"}}
},
{
  "$unwind": "$cars"
},
{
  "$match": {"cars.v.attribute": {"$ne": ""}}
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "cars": {"$push": "$cars"}
  }
},
{
  "$set": {"cars": {"$arrayToObject": "$cars"}}
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1R1I2_F2JBG)